# How do I ask "Find something when the day is Sunday"?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say we have a table where a column(call it date) is type timestamp.How do I ask something that happened every Sunday?

```
Select something
From somewhere
Where date = 'Sunday';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function:

```
Select *
From the_table
Where extract(dow from date_column) = 0;
```

Alternatively if you prefer weeks starting on Monday, you can use `isodow` instead:

```
Select *
From the_table
Where extract(isodow from date_column) = 7;
```

The above two queries are independent on the client's language. You can also use a day name if you want using [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
Select *
From the_table
Where to_char(date_column, 'DAY') = 'SUNDAY';
```

But I would *not* recommend that, as this is dependent on the language the SQL client has configured. It might fail if the client's computer uses a different locale then English

Comment: Therefore 1 will be Monday, 2 will be Tuesday etc ?

Comment: @MarkoPolo: See the link to the manual. Both versions are documented there. But yes, 1 will be monday. `dow` and `isodow` differ in the number for the first day of the month (`isodow` will never return `0` - it starts with 1 on Monday)